# Calling function on ERC20 contract through staticcall gives wrong result

Tags: remix, erc-20, contract-invocation

I've made two functions to interact with a local ERC20 token. Here they are:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract GardenTestContract {

    function getBalanceOf(address _address) public view returns (bool, uint, uint, address) {
        address sender = msg.sender;
        (bool _success, bytes memory data) = _address.staticcall(abi.encode(bytes4(keccak256('balanceOf(address)')), (sender)));
        (uint amount) = abi.decode(data, (uint));
        return (_success, data.length, amount, sender);
    }

    function getTotalSupply(address _address) public view returns (uint) {
        (bool _success2, bytes memory data) = _address.staticcall(abi.encode(bytes4(keccak256("totalSupply()"))));
        (uint amount) = abi.decode(data, (uint));
        return amount;
    }

}
```

The address I'm passing to these functions is the address of the ERC20 token which is implemented like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";

/**
 * @title GardenTestToken
 * @dev Simple ERC20 Token example yielding 10000 tokens pre-assigned to its creator.
 */
contract GardenTestToken is ERC20, ERC20Detailed {
    // modify token name
    string public constant NAME = "GardenTestToken";
    // modify token symbol
    string public constant SYMBOL = "GTT";
    // modify token decimals
    uint8 public constant DECIMALS = 18;
    // modify initial token supply
    uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 10000 * (10 ** uint256(DECIMALS)); // 10000 tokens

    /**
     * @dev Constructor that gives msg.sender all of existing tokens.
     */
    constructor () public ERC20Detailed(NAME, SYMBOL, DECIMALS) {
        _mint(msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
    }
}
```

I'm working in remix, which is why the github import works as far as i know.

When i call getTotalSupply i get back the correct number of total supply (the INITIAL_SUPPLY value from the token contract). When i call getBalanceOf, things get confusing. I dont get the balance of the address that I'm calling from, but i just get 0. The decoded output from the remix console looks like this:

```
{
    "0": "bool: true",
    "1": "uint256: 32",
    "2": "uint256: 0",
    "3": "address: 0xf348328786984162e70f08d54a272427D810124b"
}
```

**If i copy the address in this output into the remix GUI belonging the my deployed ERC20 contract, I get back the correct balance, and i do not know why or how this could be.**

My remix is running against a local ganache chain through metamask and I'm compiling with 5.13. It also doesn't with the JavaScript VM.

I'm at a loss, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Side note: I'm pretty sure that you should do `uint256(10) ** DECIMALS` instead of `10 ** uint256(DECIMALS)`. Also, instead of multiplying by 10000, you could use `(DECIMALS + 4)`. Lastly, you should use small letters for those 3 constants (`name`, `symbol` and `decimals`), otherwise you contract is not conforming to the ERC20 standards, and applications will not display your contract details (including details of transactions executed on your contract) correctly.

Comment: Also, I believe that you should change `abi.encode(bytes4(keccak256("balanceOf(address)"))` to `abi.encodeWithSelector(bytes4(uint256(keccak256("balanceOf(address)") >> (256 - 4 * 8)))`, though I'm not entirely sure about this.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what `yaya` means in your code, but I believe that you should be using `sender` there.

Comment: You are not passing `_address` to `balancOf` in your static call.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov no, im calling balanceOf on _address with a static call.

Comment: @goodvibration i changed some variable names for improved readability, and missed a yaya.

Comment: @goodvibration changed to encodeWithSelector without the byteshiftyness and it works! What is the byte shifting for? ( the ">> (256 - 4 * 8)" part of your comment )

Comment: OK, so I have un-deleted my answer (which I had posted prior to your confirmation of this, but wasn't sure that it would work). The shift is in order to get the (32-bit) function selector out of the (256-bit) hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```solidity
abi.encode(bytes4(keccak256('balanceOf(address)')), (sender))
```

Should be:

```solidity
abi.encodeWithSelector(bytes4(keccak256(bytes("balanceOf(address)"))), sender)
```

or, which is the same

```solidity
abi.encodeWithSignature("balanceOf(address)", sender)
```

Function `abi.encode` pads all arguments, including the first one, to 32-bytes.  In your case 4-bytes function selector was padded to 32-bytes effectively shifting the next argument to the right by 28 bytes.  Thus method `balanceOf` didn't find its argument.

Method `totalSupply` does not have arguments, that's why it worked.

Expression `abi.encodeWithSignature("balanceOf(address)", 0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789)` evaluates to

```
0x70a08231
  0000000000000000000000000123456789012345678901234567890123456789
```

while `abi.encode(bytes4(keccak256(bytes("balanceOf(address)"))), 0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789)` evaluates to

```
0x70a0823100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  0000000000000000000000000123456789012345678901234567890123456789
```

See [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.13/units-and-global-variables.html#abi-encoding-and-decoding-functions) for details:

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should change this:

```
abi.encode(bytes4(keccak256("balanceOf(address)"))
```

To this:

```
abi.encodeWithSelector(bytes4(uint256(keccak256("balanceOf(address)") >> (256 - 4 * 8)))
```

---

The shift-right operation is in order to extract the (32-bit) function selector out of the (256-bit) hash generated by the `keccak256` built-in function.

You can find more details about *Function Selector* in [the official documenation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/abi-spec.html#function-selector).

Comment: I cant seem to get the bitshifting thing to work, but just changing from abi.encode() to abi.encodeWithSelector worked for me

Comment: @Johan: What do you mean "can't get it to work"? Do you get a compilation error? Have you followed my description precisely (for example, have you added the cast to `uint256`, which is not present in your code)?

Comment: I get a "TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "uint256" to "bytes4"."